# Does FullSimplify with version 11.1 know this is always True.

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have version 10.0 and it does nothing with the following.

```
FullSimplify[(1/x)^n == 1/(x^n), Or[x > 0, Element[n,Integers]]]
```

However, version 10.0 tells me both of the following are True.

```
FullSimplify[(1/x)^n == 1/(x^n), Element[n, Integers]]
FullSimplify[(1/x)^n == 1/(x^n), x > 0]
```

Comment: After reviewing some cogent comments on my earlier answer, I came to believe my answer was inappropriate, possibly based on my misunderstanding of your question, and probably had an error in it.  My apologies for any confusion I have caused.

Answer (score 2):

I read your question as wanting Mathematica to tell you that

```
(1/x)^n == 1/(x^n)
```

simplifies to `True` under both of the conditions `x > o` and `Element[n, Integers]`. The function suited to that query is `AllTrue` not `Or`,

```
AllTrue[Simplify[(1/x)^n == 1/(x^n), #] &] @ {x > 0, Element[n, Integers]}
```

> `True`

Comment: My purpose for writing this was to see if FullSimplify in version 11.1  is smart enough to say my first line is True.  I hope this will motivate Wolfram to improve FullSimplify to cover this case in a future version.

Comment: @TedErsek. Since your use of  `Or` is semantically incorrect, I think is no chance that Wolfram will implement the behavior you ask for.